# Why is time taken in hibernation included in system uptime?

Tags: 14.04, hibernate, uptime

When i go into hibernation and resume then look at the result of running `uptime` , i note that the the hibernation duration is also included.
in `pm-hibernate` man pages. it states that: *"During hibernate the system is fully powered off,"* . 
shouldn't uptime be resetting to zero if the 'the system is fully powered off' or pausing because the system is hibernated hibernated, or is this a bug?

Comment: Uptime is measured from the time of boot - the OS isn't really booted during the time when you resume from hibernation - it's a restoration of a state, saved on the hard drive (where suspend is stored in RAM). So, uptime's not the best metric for determining the overall time the system has been on but, rather, is a metric to tell when the last reboot was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> shouldn't uptime be resetting to zero if the 'the system is fully powered off'

- suspend/hibernate are not considered "off". The last "wake up time" is stored in `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`.

> or pausing because the system is hibernated

- now that would be odd. How would one then know what the actual uptime is?

> or is this a bug?

Uptime is the time since last (re)boot. Basically the system stores at boot time what the time is and "now" -/- that time is the uptime. So in that regard: no, not a bug. 
The command predates notebooks and hibernate/suspend so maybe if you create a feature request someone decides it is a good feature to have. It  probably is a very easy addition:just update the time stored on disk. And I can not imagine it is a lot more than adding a call to the hibernation/suspend script. But it will also be difficult to get it happen :)